# Is there a way to compare two images if one of them is contained in the other

Tags: python, image-processing

Okay,the problem is ,i cannot get to compare 2 images together,one is the template,"the big image" and the other is an object of it . the method
find_image is from the internet,so im still not sure how exactly to work with it ,but the error is saying is .
The idea of the program is to check if on the screenshot there is "object" and if there is ,get the coordinates and get the mouse to click on it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thero/Desktop/Idling bot/code.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/thero/Desktop/Idling bot/code.py", line 93, in main
    find_image(os.getcwd(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png'), os.getcwd(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png'))
TypeError: getcwd() takes no arguments (1 given)

import win32api, win32con
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps, Image
import os
import glob
import time
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import cv2

image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\*.png"):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    print("results : " + str(filename))


# Globals
# ------------------
x_pad = 158
y_pad = 256
image_name = ""


def screenGrab():
 box = (x_pad+1, y_pad+1, x_pad+962, y_pad+542)
 im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
 im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_pic'+'.png', 'PNG')
 return im

def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    print("Click.")

def leftdown():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("left Down")


def leftUp():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("left release")


def mousePos(cord):
 win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1]))

def get_cords():
  x,y=win32api.GetCursorPos()
  x=x-x_pad
  y=y-y_pad
  print(x,y)

# def compareImg():
#  image1=cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\Copper.png')
#  image2=cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png')
#
#  difference = cv2.subtract(image1,image2)
#  result = not np.any(difference)
#  if result is True:
#   print ("they are the same")
#  else:
#   cv2.imwrite(("result.jpg",difference))
#   print ("Different")

def find_image(im, tpl):
    im = np.atleast_3d(im)
    tpl = np.atleast_3d(tpl)
    H, W, D = im.shape[:3]
    h, w = tpl.shape[:2]

    # Integral image and template sum per channel
    sat = im.cumsum(1).cumsum(0)
    tplsum = np.array([tpl[:, :, i].sum() for i in range(D)])

    # Calculate lookup table for all the possible windows
    iA, iB, iC, iD = sat[:-h, :-w], sat[:-h, w:], sat[h:, :-w], sat[h:, w:]
    lookup = iD - iB - iC + iA
    # Possible matches
    possible_match = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce([lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)]))

    # Find exact match
    for y, x in zip(*possible_match):
        if np.all(im[y+1:y+h+1, x+1:x+w+1] == tpl):
            return (y+1, x+1)

    raise Exception("Image not found")
def main():
 screenGrab()
 find_image(os.getcwd(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png'), os.getcwd(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png'))
 get_cords()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Please write a more specific question title, and just include details of the specific problem in the question itself.

Comment: Tried to explain it a bit better. Sorry if its still bad.

Answer (score 0):

As the Traceback states, get_cwd() doesn't take parameters. This function just gets the current working directly. I haven't looked too deeply into the code, but if find_image compares the images, simply try this instead:

```
def main():
 screenGrab()
 find_image('C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png', 'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pic.png')
 get_cords()
```

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thero/Desktop/Idling bot/code.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/thero/Desktop/Idling bot/code.py", line 93, in main
    find_image(r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\full_pick.png', r'C:\Users\thero\Desktop\Idling bot\Copper.png')
  File "C:/Users/thero/Desktop/Idling bot/code.py", line 76, in find_image
    sat = im.cumsum(1).cumsum(0)
TypeError: cannot perform accumulate with flexible type 
```
now the error changed :D

Comment: So you will need to continue debugging. Now search for a solution to this TypeError, " "cannot perform accumulate with flexible type". Welcome to coding!